# solving an integral calculus equation with Natural Logarithm cube

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to understand this equation here, Is it possible to solve an equation with natural logarithm without plugin a value into it? on this equation, it's just $\ln^3$ without any value, or is this a type error and should be written like this $\ln(3)$?
I'm sorry, if this question sounds dumb, I'm trying to advance learn integral calculus.
An answer would be so much appreciated. Thanks

$$ \int \frac{2}{\cos(x)} \ln^3 \left[\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\right] \ \text{d}x$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* true that $\ln^3$ appears “without any value” here. The author is applying $\ln^3$ to $\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}$. Another way of writing that integral is$$\int\frac2{\cos x}\ln^3\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\right)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: hmmm, I didn't quite get it, would you mind re-writing this equation the way it should for me?  Thank you so much for your effort on giving your feedback on this

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? That$$\ln^3\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\right)=\left(\ln\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\right)\right)^3?$$

Comment: I didn't understand how re write that whole problem the way you said it so I could answer it, I'm sorry for being unclear, I'm struggling to express it in English since English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Write $\frac2{\cos x}$ as $\frac{2\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}$ and do the substitution $u=-\sin x$ and $\mathrm du=\cos x\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Thank you for that sir!! so the whole problem will just be written as this now 2cosx/1-sin^2x now?

Comment: I will not answer that. Your original question was about the meaning of $\ln^3$. I have answered that question long ago. If you have a new question, then post it as such.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry sir for the trouble, It's just I got confuse after you said I need to re write it as.Thank you so much sir for your effort on answering my questions, I really appreciate that, Have a nice day sir, and stay safe... Thank you...

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.